# What formula will sumif a time range is between midnight and 8am?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to sum values in c3:c15 if v3:v15 is between 8am and midnight.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBZ9J.jpg)

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: desired result Is 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF((TIMEVALUE(V3:V15)>=0.33)*(TIMEVALUE(V3:V15)<=0.999), C3:C15, )))
```

[image]

Comment: I added the formula into the example for you to see.

Comment: sorry, desired result is 32. (employees who are in countries where it is 8am-midnight

Comment: Only based on end time.

Comment: Basically want to know total number awake during end time.

Comment: In your example, the value should be 40. Number of people whose end time is 8am-12am (midnight). Or put another way, 08:00-23:59.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets the value that represents midnight is 0. Taking into account that the time of the day uses arithmetic modulo 24 (1 in sheets), you only need to check if the time is bigger or equal to 8AM (as any time over 12PM will, in fact, be less than 8 AM). Therefore this can be simplified into a single `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(V3:V15, ">=8:00", C3:C15)
```

### References

- [SUMIF (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)
- [Modular arithmetic (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)